# Express package still "require"-able after npm uninstall?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node.js-connect

`npm uninstall express` successfully uninstalls express, and when I `ls $NODE_PATH`, it isn't there anymore.

However, if I run `node` and `require('express')`, I get

```
{ version: '1.0.0rc2',
  Server: { [Function: Server] super_: { [Function: Server] super_: [Object] } },
  createServer: [Function] }
```

Why does this still happen?

The reason I'm playing around with Express is because (apparently) it breaks with a certain version of Connect. Does anyone know what successful combination of Express and Connect will work ?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm using Express 2.0.0 with Connect 1.1.0, and so far it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output the require paths `console.log(require.paths)`

Those are the paths nodejs is using to resolve the `require('express')`

Comment: Just what I was looking for, found a random path in my home directory :P

Comment: This does not work (May 2012), fails with Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try `npm config get root`—that shows you where npm is installing things. If it's pointing somewhere that doesn't make sense, use `npm config set root [new path]` to change it to something that's in Node's `require.paths`. (Of course, now you'll have to reinstall all of your npm packages.)

Answer (score 1):

I currently use latest node, Express@1.0.8, Connect@0.5.10. I've been having some issues with upgrading to the latest connect/express, so I vowed to finish building my app first and then perform a massive upgrade. This combo works well for me though.